# Push background image down

Tags: css

I have the following css, which places an image across the top of the body background:

```
body {
    background:url("http://intranet/img/background-top.png") repeat-x top;
}
```

is it possible to push this image down by about 50px?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes:

```
body {
    background: url(whatever) repeat-x 0px 50px;
}
```

or:

```
body {
    background-image: url(whatever);
    background-position: 0px 50px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
body {
    background:url("http://intranet/img/background-top.png") repeat-x left 50px;
}
```